# How to change URL? htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I have

```
newsy/czytaj/items/odbierz-250zl-na-reklame.html
```

This is what I would have

`newsy/odbierz-250zl-na-reklame.html`

How to do this with `mod-rewrite`? I don't understand RewriteRule.

My .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (ftp|https?):|/etc/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (ftp|https?):|/etc/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .*\.html$ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 6):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^newsy/([^\./]+)\.html /newsy/czytaj/items/$1.html [L]
```

This will rewrite anything that starts with **newsy** and add a **/czytaj/items** between it and the html file.

Comment: I don't know where insert this line.

Comment: Insert it right below `RewriteEngine On`, you only need the RewriteRule line since you are already turning on the engine.

Answer (score 2):

In principle you just create a corresponding rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^newsy/czytaj/items/(.+) /newsy/$1 [L]
```

It is crucial not to omit `[L]`flag. Otherwise your rewrite engine may get stuck in an endless loop. Also in the beginning of the `.htaccess`file remember to enable `mod_rewrite` with:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

For more help on mod_rewrite, I recommend checking out [mod_rewrite-cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/). For an exhaustive URl Rewriting Guide see [a corresponding page from Apache 2.0 Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).