# Changing URL only for IE in .htaccess for js and css files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Consider this URL I get using IE (only for .js and .css files):
http://example.com/it/categories/catalog/view/javascript/common.js

What I need is to remove the part "it/categories/" from it so that the file could be found. Though for other browsers the correct URL is formed:
http://example.com/catalog/view/javascript/common.js

Here is what I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I tried adding these lines in the end of .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(js|css)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} MSIE
RewriteRule ^it/categories/(.+) /$1 [L]
```

but it didn't work. What am I missing here?
I found a similar question here:

[How to change url? htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301249/how-to-change-url-htaccess)

though as I mentioned, in my case bad URL is formed only using IE browsers.

**EDIT**

Found out that this might be due to IE's inability to de-compress g-zipped files (Apache). As in this question: [IE10 and jQuery: SCRIPT5009: "$" is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882513/ie10-and-jquery-script5009-is-undefined)

According to that I tried removing previous changes and adding this line in .htaccess file:

```
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
```

with no result. Any ideas why?

**EDIT 2**

After all I found that it's not a g-zip issue either (because just by switching page display language, page started working fine with IE). That means the true problem is within broken links (arkascha was correct. Thank you again!).

As I am not really into php stuff yet, I managed to get this working by adding this line in .htaccess file:

```
RedirectMatch "^/it/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/(.*))?$" "http://example.com/$3"
```

though I understand that this didn't fix the cause, but in my case at least I got it working!

Comment: This question don't even make sense; where are these links coming from in the first place, and how is it possible that you get a different result in IE?  That isn't normal....

Comment: Stop trying to fix the symptom, fix the cause insead, the broken links.

Comment: Thanks Claies and arkascha for advices. I updated the question now. Hope you can help me out again!

Comment: first, have you enabled mod_setenvif in apache ? second, maybe you need to use `MSIE` instead of `\bMSIE` in your `BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html`